# pthread on-wakeup execution

Tags: c, linux, pthreads, scheduling

How can I make my pthreads execute a function each time they are rescheduled by the kernel?

I need to identify on which physical CPU/socket (not logical core) my thread is being scheduled at and cannot afford to do this all the time.

Can the wakeup routine be hooked somehow to make the necessary updates to TLS only when the thread is actually being rescheduled?

As to why I need this: I have code which executes AMOs appx every 70ns per thread which is fine if the address is not cached on another socket, deploying the same code on two sockets gives a 15 times performance impact because of frequent cache invalidations. I intend to allocate memory especially for this which is only shared among threads running the same L3 cache. So I need to identify on which socket I am running and address the correct memory block. I could obviously call `sched_getcpu` and compare this to the physical CPU ID in `/proc/cpuinfo`, but this is a rather big overhead. I cannot afford to allocate thread-private memory for each thread though, too expensive.

Comment: I don't believe the pthreads model has any functionality like this. And, honestly, I think if you need to know what CPU you're running on, there are bigger design issues at stake.

Comment: @twalberg added an explanation.

Comment: If you don't want kernel to move your thread to other cpu, fix it on some cpu subset using sched_setaffinity (or pthread_setaffinity).

Comment: Yeah, I thought of that. Problem is that I have no control of what else gets scheduled on my cpuset. I would prefer not to go down that route if I can instead identify my current CPU efficiently. Maybe the `cpuid` 2xAPIC field can be used for that...

Comment: The `getcpu()` syscall that underlies `sched_getcpu()` (you can also call it directly) is implemented as a vsyscall, so it can be very fast - it does not have to go to kernel mode.  Reading `/proc/cpuinfo` is obviously slow, but you could read that just once at startup and cache the logical->physical translation in a small array.

Comment: @caf This is what I was planning to do, but rather do it only when a thread is rescheduled rather then in regular intervals. I will need to measure the overhead for running it on each call, but I believe that will be impractical.

Comment: From what you describe, it sounds like you're better off pinning your threads to particular cores, so they don't get rescheduled on other cores- and work your way from there.

Answer (score 1):

From what I have read in *[Linux Kernel Development, Third Edition](http://books.google.gr/books?id=3MWRMYRwulIC&dq=linux+kernel+development&hl=en&sa=X&ei=Q5rDUJvME-WA4gSYpIDAAg&redir_esc=y)*, there is no service nor interface, provided by the kernel, for what you want. Using *pthread_setaffinity* (as suggested above by *@osgx*, or, in more recent linux kernel implementations, *[pthread_setaffinity_np](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/pthread_setaffinity_np.3.html)*) or caching a TLS key per cpu socket in the beginning (as suggested above by *@caf*) are perhaps the best methods to use in that direction.